# setting default value in dropdownlist

Tags: cakephp

I have a Drop down List consisting of 3 values(pending,delivered,processing). I have to set the default value as the one from the database.The default value should be the status corresponding to the particular order in the database.so can you please suggest the query to set the default value in the drop down list.

```
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
    'empty'=>$r,
    'options' => array(
        'pending' =>'pending', 
        'delivered' => 'delivered',
        'processing' => 'processing')
));
```

here $r contains the value of the status fetched from database

Comment: Is it possible to set a variable as default value??

Comment: please provide the code you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set `$r` as selected value in the dropdown then you can proceed like this.

```
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
    'default' => $r, // since your default value is $r
    'options' => array(
        'pending' =>'pending', 
        'delivered' => 'delivered',
        'processing' => 'processing')
));
```

**(OR)**

this can also possible by setting `value` attribute of your options array.

i.e.

```
echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
    'selected' => $r,
    'options' => array(
        'pending' =>'pending', 
        'delivered' => 'delivered',
        'processing' => 'processing')
));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: "value" is wrong, it breaks the form concept on invalidation. either use the controller for default values (my recommended approach) - or "default".

Comment: sorry, i've mistaken here, i have to use 'selected' attribute instead of 'value' for the input method of form helper. whereas we can use value attribute for 'select', 'radio' and 'checkboxes'.   I'll update my answer now thanks @mark